# How to interpret the expression « Je gagnais à être connue »?

Tags: sens

> Je savais que **je gagnais à être connue**.

My guess: « Les gens en sont venus à m’aimer de plus en plus à mesure qu'ils me connaissaient et appréciaient mes qualités. »

If I’m on the right track here... What I find interesting and puzzling is that it is « je » who « gagne à être connue » rather than « les gens / on » being the ones who « gagnent à me connaître ».

> Je savais qu’**on gagnais à me connaître (mieux)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure « gagner à » can be applied with a lot of words and expressions. « gagner à [quelque chose]» means *to benefit from something*. You can for instance say

> Le vin gagne à vieillir

Which means that the wine will get better by getting older

As a result, when someone says « je gagne à être connu », it means that he will benefit from being better known. Someone who is making a bad impression at first glance, despite being a valuable person, is someone who « gagne à être connu ». He will improve upon acquaintance.

Comment: Are you sure to mean "deserve" ? I don't see the link with "*gagner à...*", it means "to benefit from something", that's it.

Comment: In my view, two sentences like "ce petit cinéma gagne à être connu" and "ce petit cinéma mérite d'être connu" are equivalent. That's why I chose "deserve". But I think I see your point, I'll try to find something else.

Answer (score 1):

(I made an edit, read it first)
I don't think it's idiomatic, at least not the whole expression.

"*Être connu*" means "to be famous/well known" , and "*gagner à [qq chose]*" means "to benefit from [something]".

You can say "*gagner à*" with anything (same for "*être connu*"), even though it's a little formal.

You can't say "*Je savais bien qu’on gagnais à me connaître*". "*Je suis connu*" and "*on me connaît" are not equivalent, when "*connu*" means "*famous*", it's used as an adjective. For the same reason, "*je suis perdu*" and "*on me perd*" do not mean the same thing at all.

(btw I'd like to have context for this sentence if you have it, I can't really translate right know. Are you talking about selling a book or being known by your colleagues ?)

---

**EDIT :** According to these sources from the Wiktionary [(Gagner (see 17)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gagner), [gagner à être connu)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gagner_%C3%A0_%C3%AAtre_connu) the expression seems to 1. be idiomatic and specific to the pair "*gagner à*" and "*connu*" 2. means "*to deserve to be better known*".

However, note that:

- the page about "gagner" doesn't explicitly say it should be used only with "*connu*"
- it's colloquial (*familier*)
- it's not an absolute truth, and the specific part about that expression are kind of poor in content. I wouldn't see them as completely reliable, but it should be better than my general feeling about what I think I know about that expression.

Still, I've only seen it used for places, like restaurants, independant movie theaters, or for an author, a novel, a series, etc. I wouldn't use it for people, in a way unrelated to fame.

The part about the inversion still holds, I wouldn't say "*Je savais qu’on gagnais à me connaître (mieux).*" (at least, not meaning "*deserve*")

Comment: Hi ! His interlocutor says: "So, (as it has turned out) you are much more frivolous than I thought you were". Then, the speaker responds ironically: "I'm glad to see that you've finally got to know the real me".

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Wait, they weren't speaking in English initially, were they ? If you translated you may have shifted from the original a little. (You said "my guess: ..." so I assume you had to translate and you weren't so sure)

Comment: It is actually a French subtitle for the English sentences I just wrote. As you can see, the original English sentence is not translated literally here, so I had to make an informed guess about its meaning. :) Anyway, I assume that the speaker says this sentence rather ironically.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Well I'm confused, I don't really see how the French expression would mean what you want, but I don't really get the first sentence (in English). Saying that ironically means that he didn't really get to know him ? Or that he's *not* glad ? Anyway I'd go for something closer to the English, like "*Je suis content que vous commenciez à me connaître vraiment*"

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine, as it's all up to the translator to decide what he really means by this French sentence! (ha-ha) I'm just as confused as you are.

Comment: “Valeur sûre qui gagne à être connue!” Maybe this is the same construction? https://www.tripadvisor.fr/ShowUserReviews-g155033-d704450-r432201834-Restaurant_Gab_s_Resto_Bistro-Quebec_City_Quebec.html I suppose it means "this safe bet should be known by all"?

Comment: Hmmmmm..... After some research it seems I'm mistaken, I'll edit my post. It's not something the I hear often...

Comment: Je savais bien qu’on gagnerait à me connaître". I knew that others would benefit from knowing me. THE on can be other people in some context that already exists.

Answer (score -3):

Gagner = Rejoindre la 'position' de ...

*position sociale, 
position géographique
...*

Here  the verb "gagner à être" is meaning "to have talent in suffisance to pretend behing a famous person".
This expression is to the appreciation of anyone who formulates it.

Comment: It can mean this in some contexts, but not in the sentence discussed here.

Comment: What is the expected result of being known?

Comment: It is not specified. The expression only means that one would benefit from knowing the person.

Comment: I do not think so. It is indeed the subject of the sentence which gains to be known.